# Local development site always goes to the default WampServer page rather than my dev site

Tags: yii, localhost, wampserver, vhosts, hosts

I have setup a local development site on Windows machine - I am using WampServer to do this.

I have setup a) the vhost definition for the site in the 'local.conf' file & b) added the local url to my hosts file as follows:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
 ServerAdmin aa@abc.co.uk
 DocumentRoot "c:/wwwroot/mycompany/public_html"
 ServerName local.mycompany
 <Directory "c:/wwwroot/mycompany/public_html">
    Options +Indexes
    AllowOverride All
 </Directory>
 ErrorLog "c:/wwwroot/mycompany/log/error.log"
 CustomLog "c:/wwwroot/mycompany/log/access.log" common
 LogLevel debug
 SetEnv MYCOMPANY_ENVIRONMENT TOM
</VirtualHost>
```

In my hosts file I have the following:

```
127.0.0.1   mycompany.local     www.local.mycompany
```

Using this structure seems to work for all my other sites on my dev machine, although I cannot understand why this doesn't work now?

The development site in question is a Yii site (if that helps) - when I go to my browser and attempt to load the following :

```
http://mycompany.local
```

Rather than show the development site it shows the default WampServer page (the same page as if I was go to http://localhost

Can anyone suggest why?

Answer (score 1):

This might just be a typo.

As a rule of thumb if a Virtual Hosts is badly configured Apache will default to the first site in the VHOST Definitions, which is probably why this is happening to you. I assume localhost is the first site defined.

You have

```
ServerName local.mycompany
```

in the VHOST definition, and

```
mycompany.local
```

in the HOSTS file. Fix that and it will probably work.

Also you should really have a definition of who is allowed to connect to this site inside the `<VirtualHost><Directory>` definition like so

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
 ServerAdmin aa@abc.co.uk
 DocumentRoot "c:/wwwroot/mycompany/public_html"
 ServerName local.mycompany
 <Directory "c:/wwwroot/mycompany/public_html">
    Options +Indexes
    AllowOverride All
    Require local             <-- assuming Apache 2.4
 </Directory>
 ErrorLog "c:/wwwroot/mycompany/log/error.log"
 CustomLog "c:/wwwroot/mycompany/log/access.log" common
 LogLevel debug
 SetEnv MYCOMPANY_ENVIRONMENT TOM
</VirtualHost>
```